# Xamarin Entity Framework Migration - Table 'name' already exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, xamarin, entity-framework-migrations

So, I have a Xamarin app with a local DB, and I'm using the command `this.Database.Migrate()` to apply any pending migration, it works fine at first, but the problem is, when I uninstall the app and install again, the app try to execute the same pending migration, and I got the error "Table 'name' already exists". Is there a way to ignore tables that already exists 'cause I don't want to delete the users local data every time they uninstall the app.
I'm using the command `dotnet ef migrations add initial` to create migrations.

Answer (score 0):

To everyone facing this problem, I solved creating a method using SQLiteConnection. You need to add `using SQLite;` :

```
public static bool TableExists(string tableName)
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);

        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            var info = db.GetTableInfo(tableName);
            if (info.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```